# Populating JSON data in a table view Swift 4

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I have got json data and I can parse the first part which is nav and name, however I need to parse the array children into a table view.

```
{
"nav": [
    {
        "name": "Home",
        "navigationName": "Home",
        "icon": null,
        "navigation": {
            "URI": null,
            "type": "CUSTOM",
            "target": "home",
            "depth": null,
            "data": null,
            "filters": {},
            "urlStructure": {
                "title": null,
                "isFeatured": false,
                "isCampaign": false
            }
        },
        "styles": []
    },
    {
        "name": "New In",
        "navigationName": "New In",
        "icon": null,
        "navigation": {
            "URI": null,
            "type": "NO_LINK",
            "target": "",
            "depth": null,
            "data": null,
            "filters": {},
            "urlStructure": {
                "title": null,
                "isFeatured": false,
                "isCampaign": false
            }
        },
        "styles": [
            "linkNewin"
        ],
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "New In Mens",
                "navigationName": "New In Mens",
                "icon": null,
                "navigation": {
                    "URI": "/men?facet:new=latest&sort=latest",
                    "type": "CATEGORY",
                    "target": "men",
                    "depth": null,
                    "data": null,
                    "filters": {
                        "facet:new": "latest",
                        "sort": "latest"
                    },
                    "urlStructure": {
                        "title": null,
                        "isFeatured": false,
                        "isCampaign": false
                    }
                },
                "styles": [
                    "linkNewin"
                ]
            },
```

That is the json data. I have parsed and populated the first name in the array nav, but cannot do it for the Children array.
I have created this data model so far:

```
    struct Menu: Codable {
    var nav: [Menus]

}

struct Menus: Codable {
    var name: String
    var children: [Child]?


}

struct Child: Codable {
    var name: String
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

I have got the structs working so when I add a break point in I can see the children's names, however I do not know how to access these and add them to a second section in. Below is my table view set up

```
extension MenuViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 32
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
        let navItem = self.menu?.nav[indexPath.row]
//        cell?.det?.text = self.menu?.nav[indexPath.row].children?[indexPath.row].name


        return cell!
    }


}
```

Comment: What is your goal here? Since there can be many children per nav and you access nav with indexPath you need another solution for children like concatenating all of them to a string and adding that string to the cell.

Comment: My end game is to when I click on the cell that is Menu.Name the table view will expand and then the expanded cells will be populated by Children.name

Comment: Ok, I don't know anything about expanding cells but you then need to access the children array using a separate loop and assign each cell with the child.name property.

Comment: do you have an Idea of the two loops you would use?

Comment: @NathanTugwell "but cannot do it for the Children array"
why is that?
are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to approach your question since you gave not enough background and information, so I'm going to assume certain things and give you an answer. Let's start!

Looks like the children node is a `Nav` array so I created the following structs:

```
struct Menu: Codable {
    let nav: [Nav]

    func getMenu(_ parent: String? = nil) -> [Nav] {
        if parent == nil {
            return nav
        } else {
            let option =
                nav.compactMap { $0 }
                   .first { $0.name == parent }
            if let children = option?.children {
                return children
            } else {
                return []
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Nav: Codable {
    let name, navigationName: String
    let icon: String?
    let navigation: Navigation
    let styles: [String]
    let children: [Nav]?
}

struct Navigation: Codable {
    let URI: String?
    let type: String
    let target: String
    let depth: Int?
    let data: String?
    let filter: [String:String]?
    let urlStructure: UrlStructure
}

struct UrlStructure: Codable {
    let title: String?
    let isFeatured: Bool
    let isCampaign: Bool
}
```

Inside `Menu` I created a `getMenu` method. If no parameter is supplied it returns the top level menu else it tries to find a `Nav` whose `name` property equals the parameter sent.
To decode your json use the following method that receives a JSON string and returns a `Menu`:

```
func decodeJson(_ jsonString: String) -> Menu {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    // Try to get JSON from String to Data
    guard let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else { return Menu() }
    do {
        return try decoder.decode(Menu.self, from: jsonData)
    } catch { // Decode, if bad JSON return empty Menu
        return Menu()
    }
}
```

Thats all to decode your JSON to a `Menu` struct, now let's deal with the UI stuff. In your `viewDidload` or any other entry point in your `ViewController` you need to transform your JSON to a `Menu` struct. Define a variable for the `Menu` and a optional `String` variable that has the current menu's name.

```
var menu: Menu!
var currentMenuOption: String? = nil
```

Then initialize your navigationMenu with your JSON string:

```
let navigationMenu = decodeJson(jsonString)
```

After all of this your extension should look like this:

```
extension MenuViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return navigationMenu.getMenu(currentMenuOption).count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
        let navItem = self.menu.getMenu(currentMenuOption)[indexPath.row]
            cell?.det?.text = navItem.name
        return cell!
    }
```

If the user selects a row you must set `currentMenuOption` with the row text and reload the table.
This implementation is trying to avoid changing your code as little as possible. Hopes this works for you, or at least give you an idea how to solve it :)

Comment: `Menu()` doesn't compile. I would make the function `throw` and hand over the error. By the way *Try to get JSON from String to Data* is pointless. Use `let jsonData = Data(jsonString.utf8)`. It'll never fail.

Comment: Menu() does compile, I have a small Playground and works fine. Thanks for `let jsonData = Data(jsonString.utf8)` tip, nice one!